# Optimization from partial solution: minimize sum of distances between pairs

Tags: algorithm, optimization, sum, distance

I have a problem which I like and I love to think about solutions, but I'm stuck unfortunately. I hope you like it too. The problem states:

I have two lists of 2D points(say A and B) and need to pair up points from A with points from B, under the condition that the sum of the distances in all pairs is minimal. A pair contains one point from A and one from B, a point can be used only once, and as many as possible pairs should be created(i.e. `min(length(A), length(B))`).

I've made a simple example, where color denotes which list the point is from, and the black connections are the solution.

[image]

Although this is a nice problem and I suspect is NP-hard, it gets nicer. I can build on existing solutions. Suppose I have two lists and the corresponding solution(i.e. the set of pairs), then the problem I need to solve is to reoptimalize that solution when a point is added to or removed from either list.

I've unfortunately not been able to come up with any non-brute force algorithm yielding the optimal solution. I hope you can. Any algorithm is appreciated in any (pseudo) language, preferably C#.

Comment: How does the data look? List A = {(3, 5), (5, 6), (1, 2)} and B would be all the points?

Comment: @James, I'm not sure if I follow you. Both list contain points and no point is in both lists. Both lists are equivalent to the problem, so if I were to interchange A and B, the solution wouldn't change. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I am trying to see how you know how many lines to draw.  And how the two groups are actually represented.

Comment: @James, in my question I literally already answered that: As many as possible pairs should be created(i.e. min(length(A), length(B)). Secondly, the groups are lists of points, each point containing two coordinates. Your example list A is correct.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This problem is solvable in polynomial time via the [Hungarian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm). To get a square matrix, add dummy entries to the shorter list at "distance 0" from everything.

Comment: Do you know how to solve the second part without running the whole algorithm again?

Comment: @IVlad The standard nomenclature would be "dynamic Hungarian algorithm" and sure enough, people have thought about it: http://www.ri.cmu.edu/publication_view.html?pub_id=5805

Comment: That is for when the cost of an edge changes. This asks for the new solution when you remove or add a node. The paper seems to present `the incremental assignment problem`, which is closer to what the OP asked, but still different: their version adds two new nodes, one to each set. It might be related however.

Comment: @IVlad To add a node, pretend as if you just decreased its assignment costs from infinity. To remove a node, do the reverse. I'm disappointed by the false advertising of that paper.

Comment: (continuing) I'm not an expert on matching algorithms, but for sure what would work is primal simplex for additions and dual simplex for deletions. Making *that* more efficient in OP's geometric setting probably involves column/row generation and some fancy geometric data structures. I'm sort of hesitant to expand on this because it would be a serious undertaking even for an algorithms expert.

Comment: @lVlad, that can be overcome. When adding a new point to one list, I just have to add a dummy point to the other list as well, infinitely far away. (I haven't read the article yet btw)

Comment: Thanks to you all I've managed to find an article solving my problem(http://www.ceng.metu.edu.tr/~ucoluk/research/publications/assignment.pdf). I will spit through this article and implement their algorithm in the coming week. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is an instance of the *weighted minimum maximal matching problem* (as described in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29)). There is no polynomial-time algorithm even for the unweighted problem (all distances equal). There are efficient algorithms to approximately solve it in polynomial time (within a factor of 2).

Comment: Do you mean a minimum cost maximal matching in a bipartite graph? That's what this seems to be, and it has polynomial algorithms. Also, your link is broken, and I'm not sure what you mean so I can't fix it myself.

Comment: Fixed the link and, yes, that's what I meant. The only fast algorithms I know of are for the special case that the graph is a quasi-convex tour. Is there a polynomial algorithm for the general case?

Comment: @Ted, Thank you for introducing me to the terminology, 'matching' in particular. I hadn't found anything on wiki due to my lack thereof. But I don't think my problem is the minimum maximal matching problem. The solution I need contains the largest amount of edges, while directly from your link it says:
minimum maximal matching [...] contains the smallest possible number of edges. It might be minimum cost maximum matching, but dunno.
Nevertheless, the problem is hard, but I'd still like to solve it regardlessly....

Comment: I don't know what a quasi-convex tour is, but wikipedia says this `Finding such a matching is known as the assignment problem. It can be solved by using a modified shortest path search in the augmenting path algorithm. If the Bellman-Ford algorithm is used, the running time becomes O(V2E), or the edge cost can be shifted with a potential to achieve O(V2logV + VE) running time with the Dijkstra algorithm and Fibonacci heap.`. Isn't this the assignment problem? Minus the update step anyway, I'm not sure how to do that efficiently yet.

Comment: Ok, I know where the confusion is coming from now. I should have said `maximum matching`, not `maximal matching`. This is the `maximum matching` problem as far as I can tell, not the former.

Comment: OP wants the sum of distances to be a _minimum_, but the matching to be maximal. That's not the maximum matching problem, as far as I can tell. See [here](http://pnylab.com/pny/papers/quasi/quasi/index.html) for a description of quasi-convex tour (and an algorithm). Another algorithm is [here](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=6659B2C10D8102FAF0224DE9C0777AB4?doi=10.1.1.137.5167&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: He says that as many as possible pairs should be created, so it sounds like the maximum matching problem to me.

Comment: @Ted Hopp Since the underlying bipartite graph is complete, there is no difference between maximal and maximum.

Comment: @lVlad, I apogise for my attempt at correcting you, it did seem 'maximal' should have been 'maximum', but as u mad says, it doesn't matter in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is the minimum weight Euclidean bipartite matching problem. There is a O(n^(2+epsilon)) algorithm.