# detailed hungarian algorithm(assignment problem) question

Tags: algorithm, graph, variable-assignment, graph-algorithm

I have implemented the hungarian algorithm, a solution to the assignment problem, as described by [this article](http://www.ri.cmu.edu/pub_files/pub4/mills_tettey_g_ayorkor_2007_3/mills_tettey_g_ayorkor_2007_3.pdf), but it fails on a few percent of random costs matrices.

I've spent weeks debugging it(I started when I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091567/optimization-from-partial-solution-minimize-sum-of-distances-between-pairs), not full time though). I took random cost matrices for which the algorithm fails and performed the algorithm with good old pen and paper, and compared that with my implementation to see what went  wrong. This led me to a few bugs which I've corrected now, but I have encountered an example for which I do not get the right solution when solving it by hand. For anyone who is interested: the costmatrix of that example is `{{0,6,4,3},{3,2,1,2},{0,7,6,4},{3,8,5,3}}`, for which the correct solution has the sum of `9=4+2+0+3`(in that order). In that example there is eventually a matched edge not on the equality subgraph, and I think that is impossible, indicating something is wrong.

Either I don't fully understand the solution, which is a viable option, or an *extremely* subtle bug in the presented solution, which I will elaborate on below.

I realize I have to introduce some terminology, but since this is a detailed question I am not going to explain all concepts in full detail, as anyone needing that explanation probably wouldn't be able to answer my question anyway.

- The input of the problem is a weighted complete bipartite graph with `n` nodes on each partition.
- The presented method specifies to find `n` augmenting paths.
- An augmenting path is an alternating path starting and ending at a unmatched nodes.
- An alternating path is a path alternating between matched an unmatched edges on the equality subgraph.
- These alternating paths are grown in a breadth-first manner, stopping only when either:

  - An augmenting path is found or
  - the alternating paths cannot be grown any further.
- And a crucial fact to the possible bug: the algorithm remembers what nodes the alternating paths have encountered, which affects the algorithm in a part irrelevant to this question.

When an augmented path is found, the presented method says to stop growing the alternating paths. I believe this is incorrect. I think all alternating paths need to be grown up to the cost of the found augmented path. Notice that the alternating paths are grown in a breadth first manner, so this only grows paths whose costs can tie with the found path. This small change might result in some nodes being marked as 'visited by alternating path' which otherwise wouldn't have been marked, which affect the algorithm further on.

**The actual question:**
Should I consider alternating paths with costs equal to the costs of the augmented path (and starting at the same node) explored? This is contrary to the presented method, which says to stop as soon as an augmented path is found, regardless of any ties in costs with other paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the presentation of the Hungarian algorithm in "The Stanford GraphBase" you can track its progress towards a solution as adding a constant to every cell in a row of the cost matrix, or every cell in a column of the cost matrix, and see that you have a solution when you have a complete set of independent zeros in the altered matrix.

I have read just once the paper you refer to. Is it the case that finding an augmenting path allows you to increase the number of independent zeros in the altered matrix? If so, then finding n augmenting paths, as in their Figure 3 step 2, will find a good solution, because you must then have n independent zeros. If so, then you can check your implementation of the algorithm by checking that each augmenting path found adds an independent zero, even in the case when there are other paths that it could have found but stopped short of finding.

Comment: Each augmenting path does add an independent zero to the altered matrix, and the solution will therefore always have `n` independent zeros, that is correct. But that doesn't mean it's the optimal solution, which it isn't in the case here.

Comment: I expect that a solution with n independent solutions will be an optimal solution because it is an optimal solution on the adjusted matrix (can't do better than 0 + 0 + ...) and because the adjustments don't change the relative costs of answers.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion over your example matrix. If I get to pick 4 squares, using each row and each column exactly once, I think I want to pick the 0 in the top left, the three in the bottom right, and two diagonal 1s from the middle square. I think that gives me a cost of 5 for a valid solution. What is going on here?

Comment: I'm awfully sorry, I made an error in copying the example matrix. A `1` should be a `7`.

Comment: I worked your (edited) example by hand and found your solution at the position of n independent zeros. Coupled with my argument above that n independent zeros mark a perfect solution of the adjusted matrix, and therefore of the original matrix, I suggest you check that if your program has found n independent zeros at something that is not a solution, that it really has got to that position by adding constants to all cells in a series of rows or columns.

Comment: You are correct, I have been treating some zeroes as independent zeroes. Thnx for the help!